# STM32 unaligned access

Tags: arm, stm32

Periodically, the program enters the HardFault_Handler. In the register `HFSR` set bit `FORCED` and in `UFSR` register set `UNALIGNED`.
The project uses STM32F417, FreeRtos, LWIP. In most cases, the error in the stack are LWIP function. The error occurs rarely once
a few days.
The program is compiled with the flag `--no_unaligned_access`.
It is unclear why there is such an error - while `--no_unaligned_access` flag is enabled and even every few days, and second whether it is possible to process or ignore this error and continue the program?

Comment: If you ignore the error and continue the program (which is technically possible) you are highly likely to have undefined operation after that. Unfortunately Hard Faults can be tricky to track down, especially when you get them rarely. Do any of the fault register gives you the address the unaligned access occurs (I know they for data faults)?

Comment: Is the crash random? What does the stack trace say? Does FreeRtos have any alignment flag as well that can be set?

Comment: @Realtime Rik Today Today there was a new event. At this time, another error. Here is a screenshot of the error information. [link](https://yadi.sk/i/FpUC-kNd347m8w)

Comment: @staringlizard The crash is random. The stack always contains tcpip_thread. In FreeRTOS portBYTE_ALIGNMENT is 8, in LwIP MEM_ALIGNMENT is 4. Here is a screenshot of the new error that occurred today [link](https://yadi.sk/i/FpUC-kNd347m8w)

Comment: @ULF21: Looks to me like cpu is reporting INVSTATE and not UNALIGNED ?

Comment: By any chance have you set a fast clock speed and not increased the FLASH memory latency? At the same time I was troubleshooting this problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614310/stm32f0-system-clock-pll-configuration-and-or-temperature-causing-error) I was getting similar memory access hard faults - I thought I had multiple problems. When I set the latency, the hard faults went away, too!

Comment: @mbmcavoy The FLASH memory latency is set to 5 wait cycles, which corresponds to 168MHz CPU clock for STM32F417. The reason of failures is still not clear, the failure continues. Most likely cause of failure is LwIP stack.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any indication the error you get is due to unaligned access. Perhaps you just have an old fashioned bug where your code overwrites the stack or other memory. You have no base to claim the error is is(or isn't) caused by the LwIP code. The code you always need to verify and blame first is the code you have written, not code used successfully in thousands of other projects.

Comment: Does the fault happen if you lower the freqency of the MCU? I had stability issues with one LwIP project that all went away when I clocked down my MCU, and I really didn't need that extra juice anyway.

Answer (score 1):

(I know this is years after the OQ. Posting in case it's still helpful.)

I'm working on a project that is using LWIP 1.4.1 that does have at least one unaligned access fault; I've just now fixed it. (I'm here researching if this is a known issue.)

In `src/netif/etharp.c: etharp_request()`

```
  return etharp_raw(netif, (struct eth_addr *)netif->hwaddr, &ethbroadcast,
                (struct eth_addr *)netif->hwaddr, &netif->ip_addr, &ethzero,
                ipaddr, ARP_REQUEST);
```

The cast `(struct eth_addr *)netif->hwaddr` is causing the non-alignment of `netif->hwaddr` to be discarded. A subsquent `memcpy()` inside `etharp_raw()` then faults.

The solution I've shoe-horned in is to allocate temporary storage that is aligned and pass that instead:

```
  struct eth_addr hwaddr;
  memcpy(hwaddr.addr, netif->hwaddr, ETHARP_HWADDR_LEN);

  return etharp_raw(netif, &hwaddr, &ethbroadcast,
                &hwaddr, &netif->ip_addr, &ethzero,
                ipaddr, ARP_REQUEST);
```

A quick check through the rest of `etharp.c` reveals quite a number of such casts, some of which are harmless but at least one or two others are also likely to fault.

Comment: memcpy cant fail because of the alignment. Your problem lies somewhere else. BTW if you may have alignment prblems - disable builtin memcpy

Comment: @P__J__ And yet, the memcpy() fails. I have pinned the problem to that exact line.

Answer (score 0):

lwIP 2.x has been released since mid-last year (2018). My experience is that changing over from 1.4x to 2.x did not cause any/much issues, so it's best to switch over. That sort of problems (if they are actual problems) might have been fixed.

Also, the F4x series is Cortex-M4, so they can do unaligned access. It would only cause problems if you are using F0xx or L0xx series that uses the Cortex-M0+ core.

Comment: I'd like to update. This lwIP is included with Tivaware and TI hasn't updated it in quite some time.

Comment: When I updated from 1.4 to 2.0 it was pretty much a drop-in, look through the config file (there are some new ifdef) and everything just works the same after. So good luck with your updating!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is already resolved. But I ran into same problem with (STM32F746) during one of the project.

Solution: Just add following line in int main()

```
SCB->CCR = SCB->CCR & ~(1<<3);//Resetting the 3rd bit (meant for enabling hardfault for unaligned access)
```

Check if it is still relevant for you.

In my case I was using packed structures which was causing this problem. After above mentioned fix with option 1, it got away for me.

Comment: Why did you add a link to this question? Did you mean to include a link to the application note? It would be nice if you could replace the link because the application note might contain relevant information. Also you refer to "option1" in your answer. What is option 1? Does the application note contain multiple options?